# Deploy code in another directory - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins to deploy code and for CI. I don't have issues pulling code to Jenkins default workspace but want to deploy code to a specific sub directory for my apache to run. The location is /var/wwww/.

Any command that I run in this folder /var/www needs sudo access as root own all the directoy.

How can I set Jenkins to run with sudo permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Jenkins user (see Systeminfo property user.name) into the /etc/sudoers file without password:

```
your_user    localhost = NOPASSWORD: ALL
```

But this is unsecure. I prefer log in as another user and deploy files using  [Publish over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin